# Fruit flies in kegerator faucets

Tags: kegerator

My kegerator is stored in the garage, and lately fruit flies have been flying into the open ends of the faucet to drink the beer (and subsequently die).  Hence, I've been getting a fly with every glass.  While some might appreciate the additional protein, I'd like to get rid of them.

Has anyone else had this problem?  How did you deal with it?

Answer (score 6):

Use some faucet soothers, or faucet spout plug. This keeps the flies out.

[image]

Comment: I like these where do you get them?

Comment: You can get them from many places including Northern Brewer, KegConnection, Midwest Supplies, and Ebay. Just search "faucet spout plug" or "faucet soother".

Answer (score 2):

Similar to brewchez, I keep a spray bottle of sanitiser in the kegerator and clean out the tap spouts after each session. I haven't found a need to cap the taps as well, and I'd be hesitant of capping them without cleaning the inside of them first due to mould, etc.

Answer (score 1):

I use some rubber stoppers that just fit right up in there.  Size 4's I think?

I also spray a little star san up in there before i plug them up to keep mold from forming too.

Answer (score 1):

The faucet plugs are available on Amazon - just look for beer faucet caps.

https://www.amazon.com/s?k=beer+faucet+caps&me=A2PUDKB6S5DQAJ&ref=bnav_search_go